# Hacer switch donde el case sea el valor de un ciclo for

Tags: java, android, alertdialog

En mi aplicación tengo implementando un botón donde al presionarlo muestra un dialogo con opciones a escoger. Estas opciones son dinámicas es decir nunca van a ser las mismas cantidades de opciones, por cual esto me dificulta como detectar cuando es escogida alguna.

Lo que pensé para resolver la situación fue al switch asignarle la cantidad de case que sea necesarios utilizando el valor de un ciclo *for*, al hacerlo asi me da un error, cuando le pongo el puntero encima del *case* me brinda este error **Case statement outside switch** .

Imagen que muestra el dialog

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código usado:

```
 btn_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

      @Override 

      public void onClick(View v) { 

           final String[] item =  text.split("\\[")[1].split("\\]")[0].split(","); 



          AlertDialog.Builder di = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); 

          di.setItems(item, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

              @Override 

              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                  switch (which){ 

                     for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) { 

                          case i: { 

                              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Select " + item[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

                              break; 

                          } 



                      } 

                  } 

              } 

          }); 

          di.show(); 



      } 

  });
```

Mi pregunta es: como podría resolver este error o saber si existe mejor forma para hacer esto que necesito..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que el `case` está dentro del `for`, no del `switch`. Lo que deberías hacer es hacer el `for` y dentro usar simplemente un `if`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) { 
   if (which == i) {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Select " + item[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
       break; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh como no se me ocurrio eso antes , con esto resolvi mi problema , muchas gracias